# create service using cloudformation in aws ecs fargate "did not stabilize"

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: Not Have Any Idea
Parameters:
  Service:
    Description: Service Name
    Type: String
  Cluster:
    Description: Cluster Name
    Type: String
  TaskDefinition:
    Description: TaskDefinition Name
    Type: String
  securitygroup:
    Description: securitygroup
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id
  SubnetId:
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>
    Description: Select at two subnets in your selected VPC.
Resources:
  sernginx:
    Type: "AWS::ECS::Service"
    Properties:
      ServiceName:
        Ref: Service
      LaunchType: "FARGATE"
      DesiredCount: 1
      Cluster:
        Ref: Cluster
      TaskDefinition:
        Ref: TaskDefinition
      DeploymentConfiguration:
        MaximumPercent: 200
        MinimumHealthyPercent: 70
      NetworkConfiguration:
        AwsvpcConfiguration:
          AssignPublicIp: ENABLED
          SecurityGroups:
          - Ref: securitygroup
          Subnets:
            Ref: SubnetId
```

I am using this code to create aws ecs service fargate

I am getting ROLLBACK_COMPLETE status with  an error message saying

Service arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:439138162442:service/yuiyiuyiu did not stabilize

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've used this kind of template for creating fargate task.

> `AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
>   Description: Docker Core App service
>   Parameters:
>     EnvironmentName:
>       Type: String
>       Default: coreapp
>       Description: A name for the environment that this cloudformation will be part of.
>     ServiceName:
>       Type: String
>       Default: coreapi
>       Description: A name for the service
>     ImageUrl:
>       Type: String
>       Default: your_image_URI
>       Description: The url of a docker image
>     ContainerPort:
>       Type: Number
>       Default: 5000
>       Description: What port number the application inside the docker container
>     ContainerCpu:
>       Type: Number
>       Default: 256
>       Description: How much CPU to give the container.
>     ContainerMemory:
>       Type: Number
>       Default: 512
>       Description: How much memory in megabytes to give the container
>     DesiredCount:
>       Type: Number
>       Default: 2
>       Description: How many copies of the service task to run
>     Role:
>       Type: String
>       Default: ""
>       Description: (Optional) An IAM role to give the service's containers
>   Resources:
>     Service:
>       Type: AWS::ECS::Service
>       Properties:
>         ServiceName: !Ref 'ServiceName'
>         Cluster:
>           - coreapp
>         LaunchType: FARGATE
>         DeploymentConfiguration:
>           MaximumPercent: 200
>           MinimumHealthyPercent: 75
>         DesiredCount: !Ref 'DesiredCount'
>         NetworkConfiguration:
>           AwsvpcConfiguration:
>             AssignPublicIp: ENABLED
>             SecurityGroups:
>               - sg-483aa03e
>             Subnets:
>               - subnet-2ce41866
>               - subnet-ceefe5aa
>         TaskDefinition: !Ref 'TaskDefinition'`

Comment: can you please upload full template to github and paste the link here?

Comment: thank you Ratul Basak  for your replay   but the problem solved  i tried the same template but i dont know what was the problem